# .htaccess Rewrite with varying end digits

Tags: .htaccess

I have been wrecking my brains as to why this rewrite is not working and I can not seem to see the reason why.

```
RewriteRule ^products/productA$ /products/product.php?ProductRef=productA\d{2} [L]
```

The above rewrite is what I am trying to implement in order for the products last 2 digits to vary. This is due to the year will change. eg productA13. The code below works perfectly but I do not wish to change the year on all my rewrites every year.

```
RewriteRule ^products/productA$ /products/product.php?ProductRef=productA13 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have matching regular expression on the left hand side (LHS) of RewriteRule. On RHS is your target URL which can use captured group from LHS. Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/(productA\d+)/?$ /products/product.php?ProductRef=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```